# Install_failed_missing_shared_library when migrating project tango to Mira release

Tags: google-project-tango

I am trying out new versions of the project tango c++ examples from [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_augmented_reality_example) 
but I'm having problems running them.
I get the error:

```
"Installation failed with mesage INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY"
```

when trying to run the example in Android Studio.

I suspect this is related to the [service migration](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/service-migration-guide). If I try to change

```
 <uses-library 
        android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device2"
        android:required="true" />
```

to

```
 <uses-library 
        android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device"
        android:required="true" />
```

it builds, but I get the error when starting the application:

```
"Tango Core out of date, please update in Play Store"
```

There does not seem to be a any newer version of Tango Core for the Mira update in the Play store, might this be the problem?

For reference, I'm running on Ubuntu 15.04, and I've also changed the Application.mk according to this issue : https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/issues/70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check

https://developers.google.com/project-tango/release-notes

The BSP OTA updated will including the libtango_device2 library.

Also The Mira release examples code have a version check, which need downloading Mira TangCore from PlayStore.

Mira releast TangoCore is out. please check your Playstore for updating your TangoCore.
Thanks.